# Inverse scrolling (aka natural scrolling) ONLY for 2nd keyboard in Windows 11?

Tags: keyboard, windows-11, bluetooth, touchpad, scrolling

I use a regular keyboard and mouse for my PC running Windows 11 and I use the default scrolling (scroll the wheel down to scroll down). However, I have my PC plugged into a TV in another room and use a bluetooth keyboard with a built-in touchpad. For this keyboard, I want to use inverse/natural scrolling (two finger flick up to scroll down).

It seems Windows only lets me set scroll direction globally and not per keyboard. Are there any settings or programs that can help me achieve this or do I need to program some AutoHotkey script to manually toggle the scroll?

Comment: No, it's all or nothing.